# How to create Text Field in Android to use in a Flutter app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, flutter

Instead of a TextField Widget, I want to use the android text field in my flutter app. I can use TextField widget but there are a few problems I get with it. Is there a way to use Android Text field with flutter? How can I set and get a text in it?

The Problems I get with Flutter's TextField Widget is:

- Can't use Autofill
- I can't change cursor height
- There's no Select all option or search on web when long pressed
- Scrolling is not smooth
- Strange behavior with text over a page or 2 long, when we hide the keyboard and show it again by clicking on a line or selecting a word.

I've read this [Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels), but I'm not able to fully understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's technically possible, by using a Flutter Platform View. This is how Google Maps works on Android and iOS, it calls out to the native Google Maps library.

Using it for an Android `EditText` is almost certainly *unusual*, but if you want, here's a step-by-step guide (just swap out the Android `TextView` with `EditText`)
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6